# Finding Out Which Tables Are Included in a MySQL Merge Table

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a couple of MRG_MyISAM tables that merge a bunch of other tables in a MySQL database.  I would like to figure out programmatically which tables are included in each merge table.

I know I could run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and then parse the `UNION=(tbl1, tbl2)` part of the statement, but that seems a little hacky.  Is there a better way?

In an ideal world, I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE merge_table = 'merge_table_1'
```

That would return rows that each contain the name of a table that's included in "merge_table_1":

```
--------------
| table_name | 
--------------
| tbl1       |
--------------
| tbl2       |
--------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any data in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to list the members of a MERGE table.

If your application has direct access to the data directory on your database server, you can simply read the `.MRG` file for the merge table. It is a human-readable file that simply lists the tables in the merge, and any other merge table options.

You really shouldn't be using MERGE tables anymore. You should use MySQL's [PARTITIONING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) engine, which is much more flexible. With partitioned tables, you can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` table to find information on each partition.

In fact, you shouldn't be using MyISAM tables either. InnoDB is more scalable, and MyISAM doesn't support any of the properties of ACID.

Comment: You're preaching to the choir on InnoDB and PARTITIONING.  Sadly, I'm not the admin on the db in question, just someone who has to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` -- see if this gives you the information